# How to parse array/object sent by ajax in NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, express

I have a array: `passedWord = ['a', 'bbb']`
Then I use ajax request to send this array to nodejs server. On server, by Body Parser I receive:

```
{ name: 'abc', score: '27', 'passedWord[]': [ 'a', 'bbb' ] }
```

My code:

```
app.post('/add-score', function (req, res){
  console.log(req.body.passedWord) -->log: undefined
})
```

how do I read my array on nodejs server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation, which accepts string as the property name

```
app.post('/add-score', function (req, res){
   console.log(req.body["passedWord[]"]); // now it works
})
```

What cannot be written as such, due to variable naming rules, in dot notation, can be accessed using bracket notation.

Comment: @Mr.Dung glad it helped. Do mark it as answer by clicking the tick mark